# Spring Boot WhiteLabel Error Page (Spring 4.0)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Pretty much the same question that's been asked for a few years now but with no avail, I figured it was time to ask here.

Why is my group seeing this Whilelabel error page? -->
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL5AO.png)

File Structure Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUZO4.png

File Structure Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p981Y.png

File Structure Image 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igSd9.png

It seems we have the general structure that Spring likes, with the main app being above all the other controllers and such.

MainApp Class:
    package com.example;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo", 
"com.example.demo.domain", "com.example.demo.dao", 
"com.example.demo.service"})
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo.domain.Book_CopiesMapper")
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

We have to have that ComponentScan otherwise we get this error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjUsM.png

Controller Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.domain.Borrower;
import com.example.demo.domain.Employee;
import com.example.demo.service.BorrowerService;


@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    BorrowerService borrowerService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("hello from LoginController");
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signup() {
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute Borrower borrower, Model model) {

        borrowerService.insertBorrower(borrower);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Success! You may now login with Card Number: " + borrower.getcardNo());

        return "registerUser";
    }
}
```

Where login is a simple login page, signup is a form that allows a user to signup to our Library, and registerUser is meant to connect to our Oracle SQL database and insert a user into the respective table (of which we assume this is the correct way of doing this)

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MySpringBoot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>codelds</id>
            <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties:

```
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.thymeleaf.cache = false

#mybatis
mybatis.type-aliases-package=com.example.demo.domain

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@dataserv.mscs.mu.edu:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.username = 
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

with the username and password for our database omitted for obvious reasons.

If anyone could provide any feedback, we would greatly appreciate it! Comment if people would like me to post additional pictures or files.

Thank you!

EDIT: the path we are using is localhost:8080/login or localhost:8080/signup. For now it seems that any path we take leads to this error

Also, all of our DAO classes use the @Autowired tag for any service that we use and similarly we @Autowire anything else we need in different classes such as DAO in the Service package and so on. Sorry that this sentence is kinda vague

Comment: You didn't mention which route produces the 404...are we to assume it is your login route?  `http://localhost:8080/login` or something else? Also, what annotations do you have on the `Book_CopiesMapper` class?

Comment: Please try removing `@RestController`  from your controller use `@Controller `hopefully it will help.

Comment: What log output does your application produce on start up and when you make a request that produces a 404?

Comment: As @RandyCasburn alludes to, I suspect `Book_CopiesMapper` is missing an annotation that makes it a component. There’s a lot going on here. Can you slim things down and share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Remove the '@ComponentScan' annotation, and as others have said use '@Controller' not '@RestController'. The '@ComponentScan' annotation overrides the scanBasePackages, so the only beans in the springcontext will be from com.example.demo.domain.Book_CopiesMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because your are using `@RestController` and you are sending views by default the rest controller sends  returns a domain object/pojo instead of a view,replace it with `@Controller`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Even with the change to @Controller, we see the same result when attempting to go to /login or /signup..

Comment: use `spring.mvc.view.suffix= .html` in your application.properties

Comment: They are using Thymeleaf so a dependency on Jasper (a JSP implementation) is not going to help

Comment: Yes! Oddly enough it was some weird issue with how we were writing our @Autowired in our classes, which allowed for that main to work out.